# D10 to DXE5: what's the equivalent of TJSONBool.Create(False) and JSONObj.ToJSON?

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe5

The folowing code compiles fine on **D10** Seattle, but my pc where have **D10** is installed is broken. Then i'm needing make a small update in my project using **DXE5** but not compiles because the commands `TJSONBool.Create(False)` and `JSONObj.ToJSON` are present.

what's are equivalent of `TJSONBool.Create(False)` and `JSONObj.ToJSON` respectivally on **DXE5**?

```
uses
 Data.DBXJSON, SHFolder;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(folder : integer) : string;
 const
   SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
 var
   path: array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;
 begin
   if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0,folder,0,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,@path[0])) then
     Result := path
   else
     Result := '';
 end;

procedure ChangeChromeSetting(const ATarget, Avalue: string);
var
  specialfolder: integer;
  pathchrome: String;
  JSONObj, ObjIpp: TJSONObject;
  JSONPair: TJSONPair;
  OldValue: string;
begin
  specialFolder := CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA;
  pathchrome := GetSpecialFolderPath(specialFolder);
  pathchrome := pathchrome + '\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State';

 if fileexists(pathchrome) then
  begin
    JSONObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TFile.ReadAllText(pathchrome)) as TJSONObject;
    if not Assigned(JSONObj) then Exit; {raise Exception.Create('Cannot read file: ' + pathchrome);}
    try
      OldValue := JSONObj.GetValue<string>(ATarget);
       if OldValue = '' then
               Exit;
      if not SameText(OldValue, Avalue) then
      begin
        JSONPair := JSONObj.Get(ATarget);
        JSONPair.JsonValue.Free;
        JSONPair.JsonValue := TJSONString.Create(Avalue);

        ObjIpp := TJSONObject.Create;
        ObjIpp.AddPair('enabled', TJSONBool.Create(False));
        JSONObj.AddPair('hardware_acceleration_mode', ObjIpp);

        TFile.WriteAllText(pathchrome, JSONObj.ToJSON);
      end;
    finally
      JSONObj.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

//////////////////////  USAGE /////////////////////////

ChangeChromeSetting('hardware_acceleration_mode_previous', 'false');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TJSONBool` and `TJSONAncestor.AsJSON` didn't exist yet in XE5. `ToJSON` was added in XE7, and `TJSONBool` was added in 10.0 Seattle.

In older versions, use [`TJSONTrue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONTrue)/[`TJSONFalse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONFalse) and  [`TJSONObject.ToString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON.TJSONObject.ToString) instead:

```
ObjIpp.AddPair('enabled', TJSONFalse.Create);
... 
TFile.WriteAllText(pathchrome, JSONObj.ToString);
```